# Binding the textDidChange event on a NSTextField to a MacRuby delegate

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, macruby

I have a NSTextField within a Window and I created a very simple MacRuby delegate:

```
class ServerInputDelegate
    attr_accessor :parent

    def textDidChange(notification)
        NSLog notification.inspect
        parent.filter
    end
end
```

And I have tried setting the control's delegate:

[alt text http://grab.by/31Kr](http://grab.by/31Kr)

I have tried setting the Window and every other object I could think of to this delegate. I have also tried setting it to other delegates (application for instance) and events like applicationDidFinishLaunching are being properly triggered.

Is there any trick I am missing in order for this event to be triggered every time the contents of this NSTextField changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass NSTextField and then in IB set the Class of the text field you wish to subclass to "ServerInputDelegate." Once you start typing it should autocomplete for you.

```
class ServerInputDelegate < NSTextField

    def textDidChange(notification)
        NSLog notification.description
        puts self.stringValue
    end

end
```

result

```
2010-04-30 14:37:24.810 TextFieldTextChanged[69109:a0f] NSConcreteNotification 0x200350b00 {name = NSTextDidChangeNotification; object = <NSTextView: 0x2003b95e0>
    Frame = {{2.00, 3.00}, {436.00, 17.00}}, Bounds = {{0.00, 0.00}, {436.00, 17.00}}
    Horizontally resizable: YES, Vertically resizable: YES
    MinSize = {436.00, 17.00}, MaxSize = {40000.00, 40000.00}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`textDidChange:`, perhaps confusingly, is an [`NSTextDelegate` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/), which means it only works for `NSText` (and therefore `NSTextView`) objects. For an `NSTextField`, you should just use the [`NSControl delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-DontLinkElementID_4) method `controlTextDidChange:` No need to subclass.

Comment: Voting you up, not because you answered this question, but because you solved a different problem I was having - thanks!